# Change nesting order of triple-nested Python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested, recursive-datastructures

I have dictionary with three-level nesting, eg:

```
d = {
    'sp1':{
        'a1':{'c1':2,'c2':3},
        'a2':{'c3':1,'c4':4}
        },
    'sp2':{
        'a1':{'c1':3,'c2':3},
        'a2':{'c3':2,'c4':0}
        }
    }
```

All 2nd-level dictionaries contain the same elements, so I want to change it to

```
d2 = {'a1':{'c1':{'sp1':2,'sp2':3}, 'c2':{'sp1':3,'sp2':3}}}
```

i.e. essentially switch nesting order. But when I write code like

```
d2 = {}
d2['a1']['c1']['sp1'] = 2
```

It just throws KeyError with whatever values happens to be 'a1'. How do I perform such operation?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you might want a data structure entirely different from this.  What are you using it for?

Comment: What you have posted is not a valid Python dictionary. Can you please fix it?

Comment: Put quotes around all your strings!

Comment: Also note that, even after doing this change, `all 2nd-level dictionaries will contain the same elements`

Comment: It looks and feels like a SQL table to me, not a dict, with `a*, c*, sp*` being the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you can use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html?highlight=defaultdict#collections.defaultdict), which allows you to define a default initialization action on a dict.

In your case, you want a reverse-order recursive defaultdict, with a classmethod
***reverse_recursive_make()*** which unrolls and reverses the key order:

- when passed in a key-value pair or None, returns a (toplevel) dict
- when passed in a dict, recurses into each of the {k:v} pairs

I'm not going to write the code for that because what you want can be much more easily achieved with SQL, like I commented.

FOOTNOTE: your version with lambdas (comment below) is perfect.

(If you insist on using dicts, and not some other data structure)

Comment: Defaultdict did exactly what I wanted. Although for multilevel dictionary it had to be c=defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda:defaultdict(int)))

Comment: Good to know. You hardcoded the recursion depth as 3, and the leaf type as `int`. I was trying to do write a version with a recursive `make_...` function, instead of lambdas.

Comment: I still recommend SQL though (or a different data structure) - this must be one of those rare occasions... mind you there is a blood-moon eclipse going on right now tonight (2014/4/14)

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing it manually like the snippet you tried, this is how you should be doing it:

```
>>> d = {
...     'sp1':{
...         'a1':{'c1':2,'c2':3},
...         'a2':{'c3':1,'c4':4}
...         },
...     'sp2':{
...         'a1':{'c1':3,'c2':3},
...         'a2':{'c3':2,'c4':0}
...         }
...     }
>>>
>>> e = {}
>>> e['a1'] = {}
>>> e['a1']['c1'] = {}
>>> e['a1']['c1']['sp1'] = d['sp1']['a1']['c1']
>>> e['a1']['c2'] = {}
>>> e['a1']['c2']['sp1'] = d['sp1']['a1']['c2']
>>> e['a2'] = {}
>>> e['a2']['c1'] = {}
>>> e['a2']['c2'] = {}
>>> e['a1']['c1']['sp2'] = d['sp2']['a1']['c1']
>>> e['a1']['c2']['sp2'] = d['sp2']['a1']['c2']
>>> e
{'a1': {'c2': {'sp1': 3, 'sp2': 3}, 'c1': {'sp1': 2, 'sp2': 3}}}
>>>
```

But it is unclear as to why you are doing it. As OmnipotentEntity suggested in the comments, may be you need to use a different data structure to store the data.

Answer (score 0):

something like this should work

```
d_final = {}
for k in d.keys():
    d2 = d[k]
    for k2 in d2.keys():
        d3 = d2[k2]
        for k3 in d3.keys():
            d4 = d_final.get(k2,{})
            d4[k] = d3[k3]
            d_final[k2] = d4
```

I may have my indexing off a little, but that should be about right.